# tkinter canvas overlapping/blocking mouseclick event

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My program is a memory game with tiles. The tiles can't be clicked unless I move the canvas with the tiles away from their original position. Then I can click where the tiles used to be to play the game.

Obviously this is not ideal because you have to click in "blind" spots away from where the game is displayed. This problem was created when the game was edited to work with tkinter frames so it could be integrated into another program.

The full code for the program is shown below. I'd be happy if anyone could skim over and identify the problem :)

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
from random import shuffle
#import time

class Controller(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        if True:
            self.frames = {}
            for F in (PageMG,):
                page_name = F.__name__
                frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
                self.frames[page_name] = frame

                # put all of the pages in the same location;
                # the one on the top of the stacking order
                # will be the one that is visible.
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame("PageMG")
        self.geometry("500x400")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageMG(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        x = MemGame(self)
        x.pack()


class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, text):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.text = text

    def drawFaceDown(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        self.isFaceUp = False

    def drawFaceUp(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        self.canvas.create_text(self.x + 35, self.y + 35, text = self.text, width = 70, fill = "white", font='Helvetica 12 bold')
        self.isFaceUp = True

    def isUnderMouse(self, event):
        if(event.x > self.x and event.x < self.x + 70):
            if(event.y > self.y and event.y < self.y + 70):
                return True


class MemGame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(MemGame, self).__init__(master)
        self.configure(width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=550, bg="white")
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.tiles = []
        self.colors = [
            "Eple",
            "Appelsin",
            "Banan",
            "Agurk",
            "Brokkoli",
            "Tomat",
            "Sitron",
            "Melon",
            "Hvitløk",
            "Erter",
            "Jordbær",
            "Blåbær"
        ]

        selected = []
        for i in range(10):
            randomInd = randint(0, len(self.colors) - 1)
            color = self.colors[randomInd]
            selected.append(color)
            selected.append(color)
            del self.colors[randomInd]
        shuffle(selected)
        self.flippedTiles = []
        NUM_COLS = 5
        NUM_ROWS = 4

        for x in range(0, NUM_COLS):
            for y in range(0, NUM_ROWS):
                self.tiles.append(Tile(self.canvas, x * 78 + 10, y * 78 + 40, selected.pop()))

        for i in range(len(self.tiles)):
            self.tiles[i].drawFaceDown()
        self.flippedThisTurn = 0
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouseClicked)

    def mouseClicked(self, event):
        for tile in self.tiles:
            if tile.isUnderMouse(event):
                if (not(tile.isFaceUp)) :
                    tile.drawFaceUp()
                    self.flippedTiles.append(tile)
                    self.flippedThisTurn += 1

                if (self.flippedThisTurn == 2):
                    self.after(1000, self.checkTiles)
                    self.flippedThisTurn = 0

    def checkTiles(self):
        if not(self.flippedTiles[-1].text == self.flippedTiles[-2].text): #check last two elements
            self.flippedTiles[-1].drawFaceDown()
            self.flippedTiles[-2].drawFaceDown()
            del self.flippedTiles[-2:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
    c.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the binding on the canvas rather than the frame?

Comment: Wow, that was such a simple and effective fix, thank you so much!!! :D
If you post this as an answer I can accept it to give you points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the binding on the canvas rather than the frame? – Bryan Oakley

This solved the problem completely. The code I changed:

from

```
self.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouseClicked)
```

to

```
self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouseClicked)
```